# Xcode SwiftUI Canvas "Content View Previews" not found in any targets

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I see others post with issues using SwiftUI Previews in Xcode 11 and 12, but have not seen this issue elsewhere.

Older project that worked in Xcode 11, loaded in Xcode 12, fails to launch the preview, no matter how simple the Preview content.

Actual preview code:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Text("I heart Xcode")
            .previewDevice("iPhone 11")
    }
}
```

After clicking "Resume" or "Try Again":

> CouldNotFindInputNodeInBuiltGraphError<XcodeGraphSource,
> PreviewInstance>: Preview 1 of "Content View Previews" not found in
> any targets
>
> Preview 1 of "Content View Previews" must belong to at least one
> target in the current scheme in order to use previews
>
> Element: PreviewInstance(destinationDescription:
> UVPreviewPipeline.AnyPreviewDestinationDescription(storage:
> UVPreviewPipeline.(unknown context at
> $1382211e0).AnyPreviewDestinationDescriptionBoxImpl<UVIntegration.SimulatorPreviewDestinationDescription>),
> previewIdentity: UVPreviewPipeline.PreviewIdentity(identifier:
> ContentView_Previews[0], description: contentType: Element
> contextType: application device: iPhone 11 index: 0 layout: device
> supportsLive: true supportsOnDevice: true), variant: nil,
> variantedIdentifier: ContentView_Previews[0], identifier:
> AnyHashable(ContentView_Previews[0]))

I only have one target, same as before, with no special configuration. I have tried reloading Xcode as well as copying all sources files to a new directory (saw that one somewhere).

Anyone else able to parse this error message or make a recommendation for how to fix SwiftUI previews?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried deleting derived data?

Comment: Yes, but good suggestion. Cleaning and option-cleaning build folder as well.

Comment: is "PreviewProvider" found in any targets?

Comment: Can you explain further? For the (only) target, I see an "Enable Previews" setting (Yes) under Build Options and a "Preview Content" Development Asset under Deployment.

Comment: is the preview of a new swiftUI project working?

Comment: Yes, it works when starting from a fresh project.

Comment: any chance you should share a link to the project?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but I will see if I can go about re-creating the problem by rebuilding components of it in a new project. I appreciate your help troubleshooting.

Comment: After spending a couple of hours restructuring my app from file->new project, carefully testing at each step, preview was working fine until quite suddenly when I wrapped the main view in a NavigationView, the error returned. I undid it, and the error stayed. Rebooting, cleaning build folder, erasing derived data, etc. anything I do it stays. File->new project works again. I think this is an Xcode bug. I even used git to track changes as I went. Weird and frustrating but I think we wait for an update to Xcode to see if it persists.

Comment: I recreated a workspace and a project from scratch using the Xcode defaults. Previews worked until I moved assets and database model to a "Resources" group. From that point on, I have the same problem, without being able to fix as well.

Comment: I filed a bug through Developer Feedback to Apple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By chance, I recognized why the previews were broken in my from-scratch-project. Reason was the "Versioning" build phase that I originally added during setup:

`xcrun agvtool next-version -all`

After wrapping that into a Previews check, everything's fine again:

```
if [ $ENABLE_PREVIEWS == "NO" ]
then
    xcrun agvtool next-version -all
fi
```

Comment: Brilliant! Not sure how you found that, as it was not showing in my attempts at tracking diffs from a clean project. That did it!

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: Where do you add these lines ?

Comment: This is done in a "Versioning" 'run script' build phase that you create.

Comment: Thank you!  I had a similar script in my scheme.

Comment: @Hardy can you please tell us where and how to add script in details?

Answer (score 68):

My scenario and resolution is different for the accepted answer.

I encountered this error today when I moved all my views into a 'Views' group folder. Then my latest view would not generate a preview and xcode displayed the error reported.

> Preview provider "Your View" must belong to at least one target in the
> current scheme in order to use previews

This error was pointing to an existing view I wasn't currently working on, but it was an opened tab.

I closed all the tabs with views that I had open prior to file restructuring. I then reopen the view I was working on and xcode began redisplaying previews.

Comment: Good tip. I typically have 3 tabs for various layouts: Edit, Debug, Unit Test are their names. Closing Debug and Unit Test fixed this for me.

Comment: Just brilliant... restarting Xcode did not fix it for me but this did 

Comment: Closing all my open tabs in Xcode solved this issue for me, too!

Comment: It's crazy but this helped, seems there is some caching problem in Xcode, oh well, what a surprise

Comment: For me I just restarted its preview with twice: option + command + enter (closing and opening).

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem! And I also noticed the doc said _"Xcode statically discovers preview providers in your project and generates previews for any providers currently open in the source editor. "_.

Answer (score 10):

### same error `"Content View Previews" not found in any targets`

> the error occurred, after I moved `ContentView.swift` file to an folder `App`

[image]

### my solution ✅

> just needs to **Restart** your `Xcode`, and everything should be fine!

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**Preview provider "Your View" must belong to at least one target in the current scheme in order to use previews**

I had this showing up .
This came up when i moved my project to another system by compressing and transfer.

It started working after - **i removed the pinned preview .**  [image]

Comment: This is what worked for me. In Xcode 15, the option to unpin is unavailable before the preview has loaded. I had to do the following:

Editor -> Canvas -> Unpin Preview in Canvas

Answer (score 3):

My case, I moved to another group folder, but I solved clicking on:
file right click > Delete > Remove Reference

Then I added back again to the project:
file/folder right click > Add Files to "Project Name"...

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have a separate package where I add reusable components built with SwiftUI, which later can be used in the project.
I had this error with Previews, until I noticed that my current selected target in XCode was not the target of the current package where I was working on.

Selecting that to the current one fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Removing the reference and adding the file back to the Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after moving some views to group folders, the issue was resolved after restarting Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.
FIX: Close all XCode tabs, clean data, and restart xcode

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes its worked by closing all tabs

Answer (score 0):

I just closed the tab and reopened it and it started to render.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs whenever we move the View File one place to another place simply you Need to Restart the Xcode then check the
Preview section in my case it is successfully run.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of your basic/default struct ContentView to e.g. MyView you also need to rename it at the top of the file. Just change ContentView.swift to MyView.swift

Answer (score 0):

Just reopen your xcode can fix this issue, it happens when you move your files relative path like into a new folder..